# Tags in photo not showing up in the REST response

Tags: onedrive

I m using the REST API interface for accessing photos in OneDrive. In the response I don t see the tags I entered on the web interface. However I can search photos with these tags !

What I m doing:

- on the web interface add tags (not people tags, just textual tags)
- with the REST API I m getting the photo information. There is no textual tags.
- if I search=mytags, the photo is returned but I still don t see the textual tags

Is it the expected behavior ?

(again, this is for text tags, people tagging is working fine and the people names are returned)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue seems that Microsoft still doesn't have a proper solution for tags, here is one more post that proves that: https://gcoupe.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/onedrive-still-no-proper-support-for-tags/

Comment: That blog post now says that OneDrive API does support searching for tags, as of Jan 23rd this year - see new post confirming this: https://gcoupe.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/onedrive-now-searches-tags/